# Calculate the radius of convergence of $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(2k-1)^{2k-1}}{2^{2k}(2k)!}x^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I need some assistance on calculating the radius of convergence: $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(2k-1)^{2k-1}}{2^{2k}(2k)!}x^k$

I tried the quotient criteria:

$|\frac{(2k-1)^{2k-1}2^{2k+2}(2k+2)!}{2^{2k}(2k)!(2k+1)^{2k+1}}|=$
$|\frac{(2k-1)^{2k-1}2^{2}(2k+1)(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^{2k+1}}|=$
$|\frac{(2k-1)^{2k-1}2^{2}(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^{2k}}|$

How can i resolve it further ? 
I thought about rewriting part of it somehow as

$(\frac{2k-1}{2k+1})^{2k}=$

$(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2k}}{1+\frac{1}{2k}})^{2k}$

So i would at least have convergence against $e$ in the denominator.. Cauchy Hadamard doesn't seem to work for me..

Comment: Did you forget an $x^k$ in the original series? I'm asking, since sometimes it is $x^{2k}$ or $x^{2k+1}$ or $\dots$

Comment: yes - updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio can be written as
$$(1+2/(2k-1))^{(2k-1)} \frac{2k+1}{4(2k+2)}.$$
The first part approaches $e^2$ using $e^x=\lim_{m \to \infty}(1+x/m)^m,$ and the fraction approaches $1/4.$ So the ratio approaches $e^2/4$ which is inverted to $4/e^2$ to get the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas too unwieldy for a comment. An useful trick to get $e^\cdots$, as you want, will be writing
$$\left(\frac{2k-1}{2k+1}\right)^{2k} = \left(1+\frac{\cdots}{\cdots}\right)^{2k}$$